# Conditioning ylim in R plot: do this or let R do as if ylim was not specified

Tags: r, function, if-statement, plot

I'm wondering how to condition `ylim = c(...)` in my `curve()` such that if `a` (see my R code below), is LESS than `.013`, then R uses its own mechanism to decide on `ylim` (= do nothing and let R decides) ELSE set `ylim = c(0, 3)`?

I need help with the `ylim` (= do nothing and let R decides) part?

**P.S.** I won't be able to use `NA` or `NULL` or leave blank `{}` or `range` to let R understand that I want R to decide on `ylim`. BECAUSE, as shown in the example below, the size of `alpha` and `beta` can result in some y-axis values become `non-finite` numbers which then makes R produce an error message saying that:

`Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values`

Some other techinquies include using `ylims = max(range(dbeta(seq(0, 1, len = 1e4), alpha, beta) ), na.rm = T)` to exclude the non-finite numbers was not successful. SO, ONLY WHEN YOU DON'T SPECIFY YLIM R, THE PLOT NO MATTER WHAT KIND OF ALPHA AND BETA IS USED WORKS OK.

THEREFORE: By **letting R decide** I mean R **completely freely** decides on Ylim **as if YLIM HAS NOT BEEN Specified.**

```
a = .012
alpha = 0.40331774
beta = 15.25120793

ylim = if(a < .013){ NULL }else{ c(0, 3) }

curve(dbeta(x, alpha, beta), 0, 1, ylim = ylim)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range` on the full fonction to set the `ylim`.

```
a = .012
ylim = if(a < .013){ range(curve(dbeta(x, 1.00139859, 1.94547309), 0, 1)) }else{ c(0, 3) }
curve(dbeta(x, 1.00139859, 1.94547309), 0, 1, ylim = ylim)
```

[image]

```
a = .015
ylim = if(a < .013){ range(curve(dbeta(x, 1.00139859, 1.94547309), 0, 1)) }else{ c(0, 3) }
curve(dbeta(x, 1.00139859, 1.94547309), 0, 1, ylim = ylim)
```

[image]

**EDIT**
You can avoid `Inf` in `ylim` like this

```
a = .012
alpha = 0.40331774
beta = 15.25120793

func <-curve(dbeta(x, alpha, beta), 0, 1)
ylim = if(a < .013){ range(func$y[func$y<Inf&func$y>-Inf]) }else{ c(0, 3) }
curve(dbeta(x, alpha, beta), 0, 1, ylim = ylim)
```

**EDIT2**
To plot in loop. I added `readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")` otherwise it's too quick for the eye.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
plot(rnorm(10))
readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
}
```

Comment: Please see my edited question to see why these methods all which I previously tried don't work.

Comment: Hi, P Lapointe., just a tiny question. How can I loop the following **to repeat 10 times**:   `plot(rnorm(10) )`?

Comment: Oh thanks, so, can I see the plot moving at some speed?

Comment: @parvinkarimi You set the speed by clicking on enter

Comment: oh I meant without clicking!

Comment: @parvinkarimi  Put `Sys.sleep(5)` instead to ait 5 seconds between plots

Answer (score 0):

You were very close,

```
a=.012
if(a >= .013){
  ylim <- c(0,3)
} else{
  ylim <- NULL
  }

curve(dbeta(x, 1.00139859, 1.94547309), 0, 1, ylim = ylim)
```

**Edit:**
It is easy to write your own curve function or hack the base version. This way you don't call `curve` to extract the range, which avoids plotting the function twice.

```
xseq <- seq.int(0,1,length.out = 101) # default values from curve()
y <- sapply(xseq, function(x) dbeta(x, 0.40331774, 15.25120793))

plot_curve <- function(x, y, a, ...){
  if(a >= .013){
    ylim <- c(0,3)
  } else{
    ylim <-  range(y[is.finite(y)])
  }
  plot(x, y, ylim = ylim, type = "l", ...)
}
```

You can test as follows.

```
plot_curve(xseq, y, a = .012)
plot_curve(xseq, y, a = .014)
```

Comment: @parvinkarimi. I edited my answer to reflect your edited question. It is much clearer to me what you meant now.